# Angular-ui: Is any modal opened?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I'm want to launch a code if any modal opens. Commonly I'm want something like:

```
    $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $modal.isOpenState;
        }, function (val) {
            //my code here
        }, true
    );
```

But I'm didn't know what to watch. Yes, I can detect open event for each instance, like:

```
modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
    //my code here
});
```

But this isn't DRY.

P.S. Also I'm can make something like `$('.modal').hasClass('in')` in `$watch` function, but this is little bit ugly

P.P.S And btw I'm using ui-router to open modals (see faq [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state))

```
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "...",
        resolve: {...  },
        controller: function($scope) { ... }
    }).result.finally(function() {
        //can put code here, but same issue
    });
```

Comment: what code/directive you use for operating your modals? that can give a better view on how to $watch them correctly

Comment: Actually I'm use ui-router and open modals like in this faq ( https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an internal service UI modal uses called [`$modalStack`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L172). This service is used by `$modal` and has method called [`getTop`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L346) to retrieve currently opened modal instance. So you can inject this service and simply watch `getTop` result on `$rootScope`. For example:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $modalStack) {
    $rootScope.$watch($modalStack.getTop, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            console.log('opened', newVal, oldVal);
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVD0cryL0qXNGl9UPMxB?p=preview

Comment: Great, This works for me!
But i want method which is bind with close modal as well, same like getTop.
Any idea?

Comment: @JayeshDhandha does this work for you? http://plnkr.co/edit/xYtmADviamG5zoGXp3MS?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq It works for me. This is what i needed. Thank you :)